# How to calculate coordinates X and Y of a ellipse with angle

Tags: math

An image says more than words.
[image]

How to calculate the X and Y.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se], not programming or software development.

Comment: It is not a question of programming or software development. It is a simple mathematical question about getting the X and Y. That then use that formula use it otherwise, it is another matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not an ellipse strictly, but a circle.

The parametric equation of circle is given by (r cos t, r sin t), where r is the radius of the circle & t is the respective angle subtended by the point at the center of circle whose centre lies at origin.

```
x = r cos (t), y = r sin (t).
```

So, in your case the nature of the circle is center at 250,250 and radius = 250.

Therefore, equation of circle => **(x - 250)^2 + (y - 250)^2 = 250^2**.

Now, substitute t = 310 degree(we need to calculate the angle in anti-clockwise(counter-clockwise) direction, so t = 270 + 40 = 310 degrees, since y is in the downward direction, that too in the fourth quadrant with respect to circle) in the given equation and its parametric coordinate as x = 250 + r cos (t) ,and y = 250 + r sin (t) to calculate the values of x and y respectively.

Thanks to LutzL for clarifying OP's figure.

Comment: Or just `x=r*sin(t), y=r*cos(t)`, since reflection on the diagonal restores the usual cartesian choice of angle and orientation.

Comment: Ok, so X = 250 + (250 * cos(40) * (40 - 180)) and Y = 250 + (250 * sin(40) * (40 - 180)) ??

Comment: No, `X=250+250*cos(toRadians(90-t))=250+250*sin(toRadians(t))` and `Y=250-250*sin(toRadians(90-t))=250-250*cos(toRadians(t))`

Comment: @LutzL - For the first comment, which diagonal are you talking about? Reflection isn't needed at all as per my thinking, it's just a matter of translation. For the second, actually toRadian conversion is implicit or, in fact not required at all. One can clearly calculate the degree value too. What do you think at this, please comment!

Comment: I did not take into account that the y-direction is down. If it were up, then the main diagonal. All relative to the origin at (250,250). -- I think that `180-t` is wrong and the correct angle for your approach is `90+t`.

Comment: @LutzL - I think that drawing a figure clearly shows that the y-direction is down as well and so the angle subtended would be 270-40 = 230, so I'm revising the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Let's test: `t=0` gives `(cos -90°, sin -90°) = (0,-1)` visually pointing up, as it should be. `t=90°` gives `-90°-t=-180°` and `(cos -180°, sin -180°) = (-1,0)` pointing left instead of right. -- Correction: angle is `-90°+t` would give for `t=90°` `(cos 0°, sin 0°)=(1,0)` pointing right, as indicated in the picture. -- So my second answer resp. first complete formula still stands.

Comment: You are aware that `sin(0)=0` and `cos(0)=1`? There are 2 reflections resp. orientation reversals present in the picture. One is that Y points down, the other is that the angle moves clockwise contrary to the usual counter-clockwise positive orientation. Thus the corrected angle should be `ref+t` where `ref` is the zero reference angle. And since we need `sin ref=-1` to get to `Y=0`, we get `ref=-90` or `ref=270`.

Comment: @LutzL - Oh SORRy, it was a mistake/mistype on my part. Calculation was wrong, x should be evaluated using cos t parameter, BUT, the thing of concern isn't that here. It's just that OP's given picture depicts that angle is in "clockwise direction" from the base (270,0) to (270,270) which puts it in the 3rd quadrant keeping in mind that the circle is frame of reference for the quadrant. *I also missed stating that the angle have been measured in anti/counter-clockwise direction. I've improved that word in my answer. I accept that reference should be 270 what you've mentioned.

Comment: @LutzL - I agree what you've mentioned about reference related to 270 degrees, the reason because I'm considering angle measurement in counter-clockwise direction. So, given required angle = 270(in counter-clockwise direction) + 40(clockwise direction) = 270 - 40 = 230 degrees. Please feel free to comment whatever is unclear.

Comment: Make some example computations, you end up in the wrong quadrant. 270-40 corresponds to -90-40=-130. This gives an x value left from the center, not right of the center like in the graphic of the OP.

Comment: @LutzL - No SIR, not at all. It has to be in the left of the center, what you call 230 or -130 seems correct. You need to carefully see that the diagram of OP is somewhat confusing but it lies to the left of the center, not in the right. OP's image clearly draws 40 degree of clockwise angle; not the counter-clockwise which you're assuming.

Comment: Would you say that `X=0` in the global coordinate system is left of the center at (250,250)? That the drawn angle of 40° has its `X` coordinate, the horizontal one, greater than 250?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93490/discussion-between-am-i-helpful-and-lutzl).

Comment: @ElTitoBarte - I've again improved the answer because I misunderstood your figure previously. It'd be 270 = 40 = 310 degrees.

Comment: With your answers I could do what I was trying to do, you can see (about) what I have done thanks to your answers. http://tprphonebenijofar.com/pruebas/sudoku (is just sample). Thanks anyway.

Comment: @ElTitoBarte - That is just awesome, by the way I couldn't correlate what is the relationship between them! Maybe, if an explanantion of a line or two would be appreciated!

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Of course. My intention was to create a circular sudoku. I needed to know the formula on how to calculate the points X and Y to create the lines that separate the tables where the numbers are. With your equation I could create circular sudoku. But even I have to set the numbers well into position. :P

Comment: @ElTitoBarte - Well, that is great indeed. And good luck to you, it was a pleasure helping you. I'm glad I could help. And,thanks for explaining.